# Update asp-route-id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm building a razor pages application, and I want to use a modal as a partial view.

Foreach loop from where I'm opening the modal:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SourceFiles)
                {

                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Id</td>
                        <td>@item.FileName</td>
                        <td>@item.Created</td>
                        <td>
                            @(item.IsConverted == true ? "Exported" : "Imported")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="FileContent" asp-route-fileId="@item.Id">View</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ((await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "DeletePolicy")).Succeeded)
                            {
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="triggerDeleteModal(@item.Id)">Delete</a>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

I'm trying to set a new value of an asp-route-id tag using javaScript (jQuery), but I cant get it to work.

```
function triggerDeleteModal(itemId) {
    $('#' + 'deleteModal').modal('toggle');
    $("#confirmDeleteButton").attr('asp-route-deleteid', itemId)
}
```

Modal (partial view):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalTitle">Caution!</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">@Model.DeleteModalText</p>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" id="confirmDeleteButton" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When pressing the yes-button (#confirmDeleteButton) in the modal to submit the form, the id is not getting passed in the asp-route-deleteid tag helper, and the id is always 0 in the OnPost-method.

Code behind where deleteid always is 0:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int deleteid)
{ 
    //code for deleting stuff
}
```

When trying to console.log the value of any attribute besides asp-route tags, the value is shown. When trying to log the value of an asp-route tag, the value is undefined.

Any ideas of how I can get the asp-route-deleteid to be passed to the code behind?

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asp-route-*` attribute works on tag helpers, which are server-side components. It is not rendered to the browser and is inaccessible to JavaScript. It is designed to work with elements that have an `href`, `action` or `formaction` attribute, and it either adds the attribute value to the query string of the generated href, or as a URL segment depending on the route template for the target page.

Generally, you shouldn't pass `POST` data within the URL, so instead, you can wire up a click event handler to the `confirmDeleteButton` that initiates an AJAX post that passes the deleteid:

```
$('#confirmDeleteButton').on('click, function(){
    $.post('/yourpage',{deleteid: itemId}, function(){
        // process the call back
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi Mike,

So I set the desired id in a hidden input when opening the modal, but when pressing the yes button, the post-call fails with the following message:
"POST https://localhost:7190/Authorize/FileHistory 400". 
Tried putting a console.log in the "process call back"-part, but it's not reached.

I noticed a " ' " is missing behind the "click", so that's not the issue. Any other error that reacheds your eyes?
Just to be clear - I am supposed to reach my original OnPost-method in the code behind, right?

Comment: Hi again Mike,

I realised it was due to antiForgeryToken validation, which is default in razor pages. It worked fine when ignoring it, so I guess I'll have to generate a token for the ajax call.

Thanks!